# Determine if a folder uses a specific naming sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm making a program to copy pictures into a specified folder based on the faces in that picture. The problem is, my program needs a specific naming system for the pictures (1.jpg, 2, jpg, 3.jpg, ...)

I'm trying to write something to skip the renaming process if it's already named to standard. (for example, if you want to retry the program with a difference tolerance, you would already have a folder with the pictures named how the program needs them.)

unknown_dir is the user-defined path to the pictures that should be scanned.
Here's the renaming function:

```
def main():
    k = 1

    for filename in os.listdir(unknown_dir):
        dst = str(i) + ".jpg"
        src = unknown_dir + filename
        dst = unknown_dir + dst

        # rename() function will
        # rename all the files
        os.rename(src, dst)
        print("INFO: Renaming file" + k + "/" + len(next(os.walk(unknown_dir))[2]))
        k += 1
```

Here's the code to call that function only if they have names other than 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc.

```
# Driver Code
i = 1
for name in os.listdir(unknown_dir):
    if name is i + ".jpg":
        print("INFO: Files already named to standard...")
    else:
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            # Calling main() function
            main()
```

It should skip calling the function if they are already named.

Instead i get the error
    `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`
referring to
    `if name is i + "jpg":`

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: `i` -> `str(i)`

Comment: @RandomDavis Haha. yeah that was a pretty stupid question I guess. Unfortunately,  I now get `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly` when referring to `print("INFO: Renaming file" + str(k) + "/" + len(next(os.walk(unknown_dir))[2]))`. Any ideas for that?

Comment: `len(next(os.walk(unknown_dir)` -> `str(len(next(os.walk(unknown_dir))`